# Why would I specify image format in a shader layout qualifier?

Tags: opengl, glsl

The OpenGL [wiki entry](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Image_formats) for layout qualifiers says:

> Image uniform variables have qualifiers that define the format that all reading operations will convert the data into...

When is it a good idea to declare the image format in a shader?

i.e. `layout (binding = 0, r32f) readonly uniform image2D input_image`

Wouldn't this shader work just as well if I did not specify the `r32f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store)

> Image variables can be declared with a format qualifier; this
>   specifies the format for any read operations done on the image.
>   **Therefore, a format qualifier is required if you do not declare the
>   variable with the writeonly memory qualifier. Write-only variables
>   cannot be used as in any reading operations; this includes calling
>   load and atomic (read/modify/write) functions. So if you want to read
>   from an image, you must declare the format.**
>
> The format defines how the shader interprets the bits of data that it
>   reads from the image. It also defines how it converts the data passed
>   for write operations when it writes it into the image. This allows the
>   actual Image Format of the image to differ between what the shader
>   sees and what is stored in the image, sometimes substantially.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same question until I learned about Compute shaders & was playing around with it. I think Compute shader is one possible use case where you read/write into an image. This is where specifying these formats is important.